# Store data from class instance to request.session

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to share some data between Django views. I have a view where I instanciated the class "Mwfrs Buildings". The class have several attributes, properties and cached_property.

For example:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class MwfrsBuildings:

    def __init__(self, form_cleaned_data):
        for key, value in form_cleaned_data.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @cached_property
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

I need to get the data from the attributes and the properties. I have the following view:

```
def buildings(request):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
        s_form = BuildingForm(request.POST)
        if s_form.is_valid():
            method = MwfrsBuildings(s_form.cleaned_data)
            html = render_to_string('wind/results/buildings/buildings_results.html',
                                    {'method': method})
            request.session['building_method'] = method.__dict__
            return JsonResponse({"result": html})
    else:
            return JsonResponse({'building_errors': s_form.errors},
                                status=400)
```

Because I can't store the instantiated class, I store the data using the `__dict__` method. This works fine for the class attributes and the cached_property, but doesn't work for properties.

How can I store the class properties in `request.session`?

It is posible to pass the instanciated class to `request.session` ?

**--------------------UPDATE------------------------**

I don't know if it is a good practice, but I figured out using **Pickle**. For example:

```
import pickle

def buildings(request):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
        s_form = BuildingForm(request.POST)
        if s_form.is_valid():
            method = MwfrsBuildings(s_form.cleaned_data)
            html = render_to_string('wind/results/buildings/buildings_results.html',
                                    {'method': method})
            with open("building.pickle", "wb") as outfile:
                pickle.dump(method, outfile)
            return JsonResponse({"result": html})
    else:
            return JsonResponse({'building_errors': s_form.errors},
                                status=400)
```

Then in other view:

```
def buildings(request):
    # some code
    with open("building.pickle", 'rb') as outfile:
        method = pickle.load(outfile)
    # Then use the instanciated class
```

__

Comment: If I were you I'd write a serialiser to save your object to a dict instead of using `__dict__`. Or you can override the `__dict__` method on your class, but in general you get a lot more than you need from `__dict__`. This way, you can save just what you need.

Comment: Can you show me an example? Or a reference?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to create a `to_json()` and `from_json()` instance method on your `MwfrsBuildings` class, such as

```
class MwfrsBuildings(object):
  ...
  def to_json(self):
    data = dict()
    data['my_field'] = self.my_field
    ...
    return json.dumps(data)

  @classmethod
  def from_json(cls, json_data):
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    return cls(my_field=data['my_field'], ...)
```

Then you can do something like this in your view:

```
request.session['mydata'] = my_object.to_json()
...
my_object = MwfrsBuildings.from_json(request.session['mydata'])
```